# Vaadin flow custom styles

Tags: java, css, frontend, vaadin, vaadin10

Hello I am trying to define my custom styles on `vaadin` components. I have the **html** file with `styles` which looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-lumo-styles/color.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-lumo-styles/typography.html">


<dom-module id="css-style-example" theme-for="vaadin-button">
    <template>
        <style include="vaadin-button-default-theme">
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 40%;
        }
        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,50);
            transform: scale(1.05, 1.05)
        }
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

It is `gradle` project and this `file` is located in /src/main/resources/frontend/styles.

I am trying to use this `style` on my `button` component like this:

```
@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")
public class BasePageView extends VerticalLayout { 
    .
    .
    .
    homeButton.setClassName("card");
}
```

But I somehow can not get this thing work. I am very new to `css` so pardon me for any dumb mistakes.

I was searching on **github** for some examples but I am kinda lost and I would appreciate if someone would explain to me how exactly can I define `style` for, let's say, `vaadin` flow `button` ? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a dom-module (which targets vaadin-button), use `<custom-style>` instead, which is used for global styles:

```
<custom-style>
  <style>
    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        transition: 0.3s;
        width: 40%;
    }
    .card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,50);
        transform: scale(1.05, 1.05)
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

For more information about styling Vaadin components, please read these guides through: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki

Comment: Updated URL for the above linked vaadin-themable-mixin documentation is https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin#readme. The content was moved from wiki to readme. Currently the old wiki pages still link forward to the readme, but the wiki pages might get removed in the future.